# Weird blocking on iOS Safari on scroll

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, mobile-safari

While trying to fix some issues with some slides on browsers, I reached a point in which all browsers work nicely but Safari for iOS does not.

Surprising thing is that it doesn't happen on Mac Safari on Responsive Mode, it just happens on iOS.

[image]

The odd behaviour is that once you reach the bottom of the page, part of the content is covered. If you scroll again once you reach the bottom, you'll be able to scroll now. It will happen the same if you scroll up at this point.

Minimal test case in which this is reproducible:

```
html,
body,
main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}


#test {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

p {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Markup is like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="test">
   <p>Lots of p</p>
   <p>Lots of p</p>
   <p>Lots of p</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

JSBin with reproducible case is [this](https://output.jsbin.com/corohupaye). Does anyone know what's happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem! is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and apparently it's due to a bug with '100vh' and ios safari. Once I changed to '100%' everything was fine, depending on where you need to use viewport heights however this might not always be possible.

ref: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-fix-for-ios-vh-unit-bug

though other sites seem to imply this might no longer be a bug.